# How to make call to analyze a receipt with Azure Form Recognizer when using docker container version?

Tags: azure, containers, azure-form-recognizer

I have Form Recognizer as a Docker container up and running per this link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/form-recognizer-container-howto

I can use Postman and get responses back like this:

http://localhost:5000/formrecognizer/v1.0-preview/custom/models

Returns with 200 and no models which is expected.

Looking to do receipt example listed here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/curl-receipts

Example is all about the service and having images on blob storage.

Is it possible for me to do this example with container version? If yes could you please shed light or link on what the request may look like? I'm assuming based on the container setup that has "c:\input" and "c:\output" in it's Docker run command those would be substitute for blob storage.

Thanks,
T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Form Recognizer container is currently a v1.0 (preview) container, are you using the container because you need to maintain the data on premise ? When using containers all the data resides on premise. If the data is on a blob storage you can use the Form Recognizer v2.0 (preview) managed service which includes lots of new feature - train with labels, train without labels, layout, extraction enhancements and more. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/whats-new

Comment: Most likely would be on prem due to personal financial data. I'm assuming the receipt model is in version 2.  I actually got it for work as far as the process, Trying to read a 1040. Processed finished but did not correctly read the document. More and better training would probably help. Will look at using the service and see how version 2.0 fairs. Just trying to see if the product will work for our needs. Hoping v2 makes it to container as well as we may always have to have on prem.